# How to inflate fragment TextView in other activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-inflate

I want to use one fragment for 3 activities and I need to inflate those two TextView's in other activity which does not extends to fragments. So basically I want to use one fragment for different activities and and reference items of those fragments in these activities.

Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_weight="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Room Rates"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/roomrate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:text="@string/pricing_impiana"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rev"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="318dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Reviews"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="253dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ratinghotel"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="4.3 Stars 2,203 Google reviews"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/webbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="89dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="Visit Website"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/callbtn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/webbtn"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="call"
    android:src="@drawable/call" />
```

Have tried like this

```
View inflatedView;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView roomrate;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clover_home);


        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.impianapricing,null);


    roomrate =(TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.impianapricing,viewGroup,false).findViewById(R.id.roomrate);
    roomrate.setText("New Text");
```

but I am getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: make public method inside that set dynamic text into textview into common fragement.

Comment: For that first I have to reference the textview by findViewbyid without reference I can't settext

Comment: You call `inflate` twice -- first on the return value from `LayoutInflater.from(this)`, then on the `inflater` field. Has the `inflater` field been initialized? And: No reason to inflate `R.layout.impianapricing` twice. Call `findViewById` on the returned `viewGroup`. (You don't say _which_ `inflate` invocation is on a null object, but I'm guessing the latter.)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null pointer exception due to the follow line

```
roomrate =(TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.impianapricing,viewGroup,false).findViewById(R.id.roomrate);
```

This is because you just declare the variable `inflate` but never actually assign it a value. So inflate is actually null and you end up calling `LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)` on a null object reference.

Comment: So how I declare it?

Comment: you could use inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);